# Закрытие сокета

Tags: java, сеть

Есть сервер, который принимает подключения. Планирую функцию удаления клиента.
Для каждого соединения 2 потока - на прием и на отправку. При удалении этого клиента буду убивать оба потока (счетчики в циклах while, которые в run функциях потоков, приравняю к false). Вопрос, как лучше закрыть сокет, если закрою в одном потоке, а другом не вылетит исключение?

Answer (score 2):

А сделайте один поток "Demon" и вызовите его из другого, тогда при закрытие потока(который не "Demon") будет автоматически "Demon" прекращаться.

Comment: только не `Demon`, а `Daemon` - язык учите!